# apt-get error with libmza

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt

I am getting the following error when I try to update something

```
apt-get: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12)
```

also this error

```
dpkg-deb: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.so.5: no version information available (required by dpkg-deb)
```

Please help me to fix this error :)

Comment: `liblzma.so` is already in Ubuntu (see `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so` and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0`, and you didn't need to recompile it. Unless you _really_ need it, I recommend you remove `liblzma` from `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 so if remove the liblzma from the /usr/local/lib will I get rid of all the errors ?? my system doesn't crashes right

Comment: got it done :) ty @saiarcot895 no errors and working fine ;)

Comment: Changed to a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`liblzma.so` is already in Ubuntu (see `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so` and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0`, and you don;t need to recompile it. Unless you really need it, I recommend you remove all references to `liblzma` from `/usr/local/lib`.